# Wordpress default audio playlist - how to add custom caption?

Tags: audio, playlist

The wordpress default audio playlist shows the caption of the media file in the list. Is there any way I can add custom title while creating playlist?

I am using the same audio file in 2 playlists, and I need the playlists to display different captions for it. What can I do?

Comment: No....I have to do this many manyyyy times. Several playlists and countless audio files...

Comment: I converted the comments to an answer, not adding more details though, just because it is a bit better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, then you can't do that with the playlist shortcode by default.

How often does this case happen? If it rarely happens, it might be easiest to upload the file a second time, and change the caption, information as needed.

Create your own playlist shortcode code based on the default one found in [`wp-includes/media.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media.php#L2000). As for the approach, for example, if custom shortcode attribute is present, then replace caption (title or whatever), secondary information can be saved in custom fields, else keep the default. You can deregister the default shortcode and then register your custom code to `[playlist]`.